# Changing flexbox width values for mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently learning flexbox to create a grid. So far, I've created halves and quarters.

When I get to 1048px within the viewport, I'd like my quarters to split into halves, like so:

[image: Quarter Blocks]

Changing the width to 48% doesn't have the expected result. What do I need to change here?

This is what I have so far.

```css
/*---------------------
Half
Distributes items equally without a gutter
----------------------*/
.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
}

/*---------------------
Quarter
Distributes items equally with a gutter
----------------------*/
.quarter-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.quarter-grid .col {
  flex: none;
  width: 22%;
}


/* 1024px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024) {
  .quarter-grid .col {
    width: 48%;
  }
}

/*---------------------
Other styles
----------------------*/
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Half Grids</h2>

<div class="grid">

  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532517308734-0565178471d2" alt="Img from Unsplash">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532517308734-0565178471d2" alt="Img from Unsplash">
  </div>
  
</div>

<h2>Quarter Grids</h2>

<div class="quarter-grid">

  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532517308734-0565178471d2" alt="Img from Unsplash">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532517308734-0565178471d2" alt="Img from Unsplash">
  </div>
  
    <div class="col">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532517308734-0565178471d2" alt="Img from Unsplash">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532517308734-0565178471d2" alt="Img from Unsplash">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Are you after making them wrap to the line below when the browser gets to a certain width? If so `flex-wrap: wrap` would be where you start. You can learn more about flex wrapping at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS property to your column:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

It will wrap flex box if there is no available space.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!